# Use a function that needs an argument for onclick event (python turtle)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I'm trying a drawing tool for Turtle, I want to be able to change the color of my brush. How do I use onclick() for a function that takes an argument 'color' ?

```
import turtle

red_color = turtle.Turtle()
red_color.color('red', 'red')

def switch_color(color): 
    brush.color(color)

def main():

    red_color.onclick(switch_color, 1)  # how do I choose the color I want it to change to

    screen.mainloop() 

main()
```

Comment: You can create a closure that binds the color argument (if you're willing to let the color be fixed per binding).  If you want to obtain the color dynamically, then you need to describe where you want it to come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is the problem you're trying to solve is that event handlers like `onclick()` don't take arbitrary arguments but you you'd like to pass one in.  The typical approach to this problem is to introduce a `lambda` expression, but I prefer `partial()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial

def switch_color(color, x, y):  # x & y supplied by onclick event
    brush.color(color)

screen = Screen()

brush = Turtle()
brush.color('red')

brush.onclick(partial(switch_color, 'green'))

screen.mainloop()
```

When you click on the red cursor, it will turn green.  Probably not the exact functionality you desire but one way to pass arguments to event handlers.